# How to send messages on whatsapp without opening the app using react-native?

Tags: react-native, whatsapp

Is there a way to automatically send messages on WhatsApp using react-native? If not, can I use bridge to do it on android?

Answer (score 1):

If this is only for whats app you can use this link

```
https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext
```

where `whatsappphonenumber` is country-code + phone-number without '+' sign
eg for India: `919876543210`

and `urlencodedtext` is the message you want to send

this will open whatsapp chat and copy the message to the input field

Comment: for android, encoding the message works fine, but on ios, in my case, + sign is omitted and if i encode it, it is shown in the same form on whatsapp i.e, %2B%

Answer (score 0):

you can use linking like this:

```
export const sendWhatsAppMessage = link => {
 if (!isUndefined(link)) {
  Linking.canOpenURL(link)
   .then(supported => {
     if (!supported) {
      Alert.alert(
        'Please install whats app to send direct message'
      );
    } else {
      return Linking.openURL(link);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
} else {
  console.log('sendWhatsAppMessage -----> ', 'message link is undefined');
 }
};
```

Comment: this won't help as I it opens the app to send the message. I don't want to open the WhatsApp app and it should send in background instead.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to send message in background without opening whatsapp, may be for WhatsApp security reasons and may be there is no such method to do so till now. but I would appreciate if such happens.

Comment: well there are many chat bubble apps show their own view of WhatsApp. How do they achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this module

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share

Hope this will be helpful!